# JSP include dynamic page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've got some of my include pages stored in the Servlet context. I want to include some pages inside a JSP dynamically, but I can't. 
What I do is:

```
<jsp:include page="<%=(String)application.getAttribute("headURL")%>"/>
```

But it gives me an error related to the quotes. I've tried to change it to:

```
<jsp:include page="<%=(String)application.getAttribute(\"headURL\")%>"/>
```

But it neither doesn't works.

How could I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the value of headURL. Is it a real URL or just a path of a JSP file?

Comment: it would be a path of a JSP file like:
   /Project/WEB-INF/jspf/head.jspf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
<jsp:include page="${headURL}"></jsp:include>
```

First, Servlet container will lookup headURL in Page scope, then Request scope, then Session scope, and then Application scope (your case)

headURL must be set at somewhere into Application scope before the JSP invoked.

BUT I think It must be **/WEB-INF/jspf/head.jspf** ( app name need to be removed )

Answer (score 1):

You can use Expression language to access the URL. So you dont need to escape quotes.

Here is an example you can do this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:set value="/WEB-INF/jspf/head.jspf" var="headURL" scope="application" />
    <jsp:include page="${headURL}"></jsp:include>
</body>
</html>
```

The file located in `/Project/WebContent/WEB-INF/jspf/head.jspf` will be included.

EDIT:
This line is only for the test. I set a context attribute `headURL`:

```
<c:set value="/WEB-INF/jspf/head.jspf" var="headURL" scope="application" />
```

You need only:

```
<jsp:include page="${headURL}"></jsp:include>
```

And a Path relative to the WebContent.

Comment: But I don't want to write the URL "/WEB-INF/jspf/head.jspf" in the file. I want to read it from a context attribute.

Comment: clarification added.